# How to open modal when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, modal-dialog

In the comments section on a blog I'm coding I want the admin to be able to delete a comment.

I have a button next to each comment and I want a modal box to be opened when the `delete button` is clicked.

In this modal box I want to ask again if the comment should be deleted or not, if yes then it should lead me back to the post and the comment should be deleted.

**Do I need javascript to do this? Unfortunately I'm new to php and I wondered if it's possible to only do it with html & css.**

I have a `PostsController.php` in which the site is rendered (action page) and I have the `CommentsRepository.php` in which the connection to the db table `comments` takes place.

This is the part of the comment section:

```
<div class="comments-list">
 <?php foreach ($comments AS $comment): ?>
  <div class="one-comment">
   <p><?php echo e($comment->content); ?></p>
   <div class="one-comment-edit">
    <input type="button" value="x" name="delete" class="delete-comment" />
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I know how to do the query, but I don't know how to open the modal box when the button is clicked.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me, especially if I need javascript to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't **need** javascript, but it sure makes the thing easier!

I've found some examples of pop-up that are opened without any javascript. I find this one intersting:

- [Pure CSS popup/modal box without
  javascript](https://codepen.io/peiche/pen/vhqym)

To do so, they create a pop-up with a `visibility: hidden;` css attribute, and they use the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class to set this attribute to `visibility: visible;`

To trigger the *target* pseudo-class, they create a link (that acts like a button) that references the *ID* of your pop-up.

The link will target your pop-up, triggering the *target* pseudo-class, and showing your pop-up!

There is also the *Bootstrap* option, as recommended by Jeppe Spanggaard, which works fine!

Hope it helped in any way!

Comment: This is great, thank you very much it helped me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, @ofmiceandmoon ! Good luck with your blog!

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript for this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

But if you use Bootstrap there is an easier way: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

Answer (score 1):

You can use SweetAlert for your cause, it is more elegant and easy to use.

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

here's working example: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6cz8mb0/)

Simply on Delete Button click
Apply following Code

```
Swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})
```

Here's how it will look,
[image: Sweet Alert Example]

**EDIT**

Based on your comment I think this might be helpfull [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5j1k4nb/)

You can customize the popup like this [Example](https://codyhouse.co/demo/simple-confirmation-popup/index.html)

Comment: This is really cool, thanks! I will use it when I have more experience, right now I want to learn how to code stuff like this, so i'd prefer to not use any of these (indeed great) helpers :)